# Browser error for XML code: "not well-formed"

Tags: html, xml

I have the following XML code. Each time that this code is loaded into the browser, i get a `not well-formed`. What could be the issue?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Auth form example</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <form action="/login" method="post">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>Username: <input type="text" name="username"/></td>
            <tr>
              <td>Password: <input type="text" name="password"/></td>
            <tr>
              <td><input type="submit" value="Login"></td>
          </table>
        </form>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Just a wild guess, but I assume, that it's not well-formed. Or, a wee bit more specific, your `<meta>` element is not closed _and_ has an unquoted attribute value. Also the `<input>` is unclosed.

Comment: And your `<tr>`s are not closed. Yep, I think the reason is, that you try to feed not well-formed XML to an XML parser...

Comment: That's not XML so is not well formed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Four things:

1. None of the `<tr>` has a closing tag.
2. `<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">` should be `<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />`
3. `<input type="submit" value="Login">` should be `<input type="submit" value="Login" />`.
4. The `http-equiv=Content-Type` should be `http-equiv="Content-Type"`. Quotes missing.

**Final Working**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Auth form example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="/login" method="post">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Username: <input type="text" name="username"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Password: <input type="text" name="password"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="submit" value="Login" /></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```